# IP in DDG is not known VPN/TOR

Tags: deanonymization

Today I upgraded to Tor 6.0, I use Tor with a vpn with psuedo random exit countries habitually. While having 5.5 I noticed when I entered IP into DuckDuckGo while using vpn/tor it was Your IP address is 184.72.106.52 in Ashburn, Virginia, United States (20147) which kinda freaked me the fuck out we all know the beasts that roam in Virginia.. Well after upgrading I find the same ip from DDG which is fucked cause I cannot find any leaks from my vpn to tor DNS or otherwise mind you my IP on exit node verify shows the exit node as does the Tor button but DDG is showing I am in virginia and the whois says Amazon so.. wtf?

Comment: It sounds like somebody is running an exit node in Amazon EC2 in the "us-east-1" region, which happens to be in Virginia. Not *all* of Virginia is scary beasts. What's your question?

Comment: ok..I am aware tor nodes exist on amazon servers, why is every other what is your ip website showing me the actual tor exit node I'm connected to and ONLY Duckduckgo is showing me in Ashburn VA. And I do not mean sporadically I mean everytime I type IP in DDG. Tanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Scratch that, you're using their onion, the IP it reports is the IP making the connection, which is where their onion is connect from and entirely unrelated to you, Tor, or your VPN.

Try using their non-onion address.

`$ curl -i -x socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050 http://184.72.106.52/
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
<SNIP>
Location: https://duckduckgo.com/
<SNIP>`

Comment: I have a epi pen. When my friend was dying I think he really wanted me to have it.